# How to use Split() method in Android

Tags: java, android, string, list, split

I have String like this.

ex:-

```
String myString = "A=myPage{a1,b1,c1};B=myPage{a2,b2,c2};C=myPage{a3,b3,c3};"
```

I need to put each `{_,_,_}` part into List. like:

**If**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList()
```

**then,**

```
list[0]="a1,b1,c1", 
list[1]="a2,b2,c2", 
list[2]="a3,b3,c3"
```

I tried to use split, but I don't know how to apply it into this for getting my result.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
    list = Arrays.asList(myString.split(";"));
}
```

Using this code I can split this from ";" like

```
list[0] = A=myPage{a1,b1,c1}, 
...,
etc.
```

Can anyone please tell me how to use this method or any other method to make success my task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use Pattern and Matcher classes. The below regex will capture the text present inside curly braces and then it would add them to the list variable.

```
String myString = "A=myPage{a1,b1,c1};B=myPage{a2,b2,c2};C=myPage{a3,b3,c3};";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{([^{}]*)\\}").matcher(myString);
while(m.find())
{
    list.add(m.group(1));
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

again split your string by **myPage** and get 2nd part of split result will do your work... don't go through hard.